# How to add selected values from multiple listboxes to a specific range?

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a code that will loop through my selected listbox item and copy them to a specific column in my worksheet. I have 3 listboxes with all different listcounts (listbox1 has 4 choices, Listbox2 has 10 choices and listbox3 has 5 choices). I want the code to be able to loop through and copy the data on every row.

Here is an example of the results I am having:
Listbox1: item1 (selected) item2 (not selected) item3 (not selected) item 4 (not selected)
Listbox2: item1 (selected) (all other items not selected)
Listbox3: item1 to item5 (selected).

I would like to program to copy the selected items in the following way:

Column B (Refers to listbox1): Item 1; Item 1; Item 1; Item 1; Item 1: (Total of 5 times)
Column C (Refers to listbox2): Item 1; Item 1; Item 1; Item 1; Item 1: (Total of 5 times)
Column D (Refers to listbox3): Item 1; Item 2: Item 3: Item 4; Item 5

I have tried the code below, but it only copies the items 1 to items 5 of listbox3.

```
Private Sub Add_Level_Click()
Dim lItem As Long, lItem2 As Long, lItem3 As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Development Plan")
    With ws
        For lItem3 = 0 To Me.ListBox3.ListCount - 1
                    If Me.ListBox3.Selected(lItem3) Then .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Me.ListBox3.List(lItem3)
                        Next
        For Item2 = 0 To Me.ListBox3.ListCount - 1
                    If Me.ListBox2.Selected(lItem2) Then .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Me.ListBox2.List(lItem2)
                        Next
        For Item = 0 To Me.ListBox3.Selected(Item)
                    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Me.ListBox1.List(lItem)
                        Next
```

Screenshot of Desired outcome:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd11e.png]

Userform Selection:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVppy.png]

Comment: Why do all your loops reference `Listbox3`?

Comment: Since Listbox3 has the most items selected, I thought this would make it copy the selections from listbox1 and listbox2 with the selection of listbox3

Comment: Why not just reference the respective listbox in each case. I'm surprised you don't get an error. Not sure your last loop makes sense `For Item = 0 To Me.ListBox3.Selected(Item)`? Can you post a screenshot - can't really work your data out from the question?

Comment: Upload it somewhere and add a link. What happens if two items are selected - your logic isn't clear to me at least?

Comment: I have added the screenshots to the question!

Comment: So the first two listboxes only allow a single selection?

Comment: No they allow for more, but the make this easier I only selected 1 of each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happens if more than one item is selected in all boxes, but on the assumption that only one is selected in the first two boxes, try this, amending control/button/ranges names as appropriate.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

With Me
    For i = 0 To .ListBox3.ListCount - 1
        If .ListBox3.Selected(i) Then
            Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .ListBox3.List(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 0 To .ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If .ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(j).Value = .ListBox1.List(i)
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 0 To .ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If .ListBox2.Selected(i) Then
            Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(j).Value = .ListBox2.List(i)
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

[image]